# How is SSL certificated checked?

Tags: tls

When you establish a new SSL connection, during handshake the server sends you his certificate together with public key. Then the browser checks the certificate againts CA. However I do not understand based on what the CA decides that the server I want to talk to is the corrent one ? Is it based on the IP address ?

Comment: *" what the CA decides that the server I want to talk to is the corrent on"* - the CA "decides" nothing. It has no active role in validation of the certificate.

Comment: If the certificate is public and everyone can ask the server to send the certificate, what is preventing me from stealing it ?

Comment: The fact that the certificate is public but the matching private key not. And the private key is needed to prove ownership of the certificate inside the TLS handshake, i.e. "authentication".